# Page updating when trying to use a button that activates try{} catch{} in script

Tags: javascript, html, try-catch

In the original script, when there is no value in the text bar and I click on the button called `Radar 2`, the page is automatically refreshed, as I understand it, as it generates an error in the function, the page refreshes because of that.

To prevent this error and this forced update, I tried using `try{} catch{}`, so if there is an error when trying to parse the first function, open a blank iframe.

But the page keeps updating when I click the `Radar 2` button.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and what the correct script would look like for my needs.

The original script works as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="url-setter2">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 2</button>
<input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" style="width: 282px;" />
<iframe id="the-frame2" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter2'), url = document.getElementById('url2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame2');
        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
    let link = document.getElementById("url2").value;
    let value2 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
    value2 = value2.split("/")[0];
            event.preventDefault();
            the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value2;
        };
    }());
</script>
```

My Script Error Test:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        "use strict";
        var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter2'), url = document.getElementById('url2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame2');
        url_setter.onsubmit = try {
    function (event) {
    let link = document.getElementById("url2").value;
    let value2 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
    value2 = value2.split("/")[0];
            event.preventDefault();
            the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value2;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
    function (event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  the_iframe.src ="";
              }
    };
    }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `type="submit"` will try to send the form data to the server for processing which is why the page refreshes.

Instead try using `<button onclick="myFunction()">Radar 2</button>` where
`myFunction()` is a function with your javascript code in it